# how to block UI during data fetching in windows form c#

Tags: c#, winforms

```
this.Enabled = false;
LoadAllQCDetails();
this.Enabled = true;
```

`LoadAllQCDetails()`: this is method takes upto `40` sec; during this time if user *click button* multiple times (even though `this.Enabled = false`)  after `this.Enabled = true` it will execute all click events, I need to *block all click events during this time*

Comment: You can disable you button while your work is processing and then again enable you button while your work has been completed. **Button1.Enable = False;**

Comment: You can flush the message queue before enabling the button (by calling the famous `Application.DoEvents()`). Although blocking the UI thread for 40 sec is not a good idea at all.

Comment: I would also like to add that async/await can help you to unblock the UI. Be responsive and flexible with the customer in front of the UI.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a task to prevent UI blocking such as the following:

```
 await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() => LoadData());

 private async System.Threading.Tasks.Task LoadData()
    {
      LoadAllQCDetails();
      btn.Enabled = true;
    }
```

Comment: I have the feeling that you misunderstood the question. For once OP is actually asking how to block the UI on purpose